# Oozie Sqoop Job went to infinite running mode

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a sqoop job in oozie which will fetch data from the ms sql server. when i run the command "oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config home/uadmin/Ramesh/sqoop/job.properties -run" job is getting created. but  when i check the status of the job info it is infinite running state.

```
log of the oozie job:

2018-04-12 19:44:14,937  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2018-04-12 19:44:14,938  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2018-04-12 19:44:14,938  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2018-04-12 19:44:14,997  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
2018-04-12 19:44:14,997  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W
2018-04-12 19:44:15,012  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] Start action [0000001-180412153027255-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]

warning in oozie log:
SERVER[hdn03.sasken.com] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] libpath [hdfs://hdn03.sasken.com:8020/user/sqoop_oozieJob/lib] does not exist




workflow
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="sqoop-wf">
    <start to="sqoop-node"/>
    <action name="sqoop-node">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${FileLocation}/output-data/sqoop"/>
                <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${FileLocation}/output-data"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <command>import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.38.21;username =sad;password =pass;database=sample --table usage1 --split-by RGE_IND --target-dir ${nameNode}/user/${FileLocation}/output-data</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>



job.properties

nameNode=hdfs://hdn03.sasken.com:8020
jobTracker=hdn04.sasken.com:2181
queueName=default
FileLocation=sqoop_oozieJob/sqoop
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${FileLocation}/
```

I'm just struck with what is the error, any suggestions guys ?

Comment: Run the sqoop command from CLI and check if you are seeing the same behaviour, that way you will know if the issue is in sqoop job or oozie and start debugging from there.

Comment: @roh thanks for the response, this is the command that is running successfully                    sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.38.21;database=sample" --username sad --password pass --table "usage1" --split-by RGE_IND --target-dir "/usage_test". Here am i doing wrong representation inside <command> tag in workflow.xml ?